# Login field for user 'root' ...Localhost Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, localhost, sqlconnection

im trying to store som data into mysql database on localhos
but i got this message: 
Login field for user 'root

im sure about the uid and pws are right.

```
  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String connection = "server=localhost; user =root; Pwd=password;database=skradderi;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO kunder(Namn ,Adress ,telfon ,OrgNr)VALUES ('" + txtboxName.Text + "','" + txtboxAdress.Text + "','" + txtboxPostNr.Text + "','" + txtOrgNr.Text + "')");
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried "server=(local);..." instead of "server=localhost;..."?
Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Connection field at all

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it wasnt working.
The connection String is for Mysql, but im using Sql connection.
the right connection string is :

" Data Source=ENTERPRISE-PC;Initial Catalog=skradderi;Integrated Security=True ";